# synctex(busy) latex file not compiling

Tags: compiling

I am trying to compile a latex file but I noticed that the file ``freezes" at the point of this array:

```
\[\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13}\\
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\
a_{31} & a_{23} & a_{33}
\end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{c}
u_{t}^{\tau} \\
u_{t}^{g} \\
u_{t}^{y}
\end{array}\right)
=
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
b_{11} & b_{12} & b_{13}\\
b_{21} & b_{22} & b_{23} \\
b_{31} & b_{23} & b_{33}
\end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{c}
e_{t}^{\tau} \\
e_{t}^{g} \\
e_{t}^{y}
\end{array}\right)
\]
```

That array was a copy and paste from another latex file. Is there a particular package that creates this problem ? Once I remove the array from the file it compiles with no problems.  The document class that I use is {book} with the following sample of packages:

```
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 9.5in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath, mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
```

Comment: Can you put your code fragments together so we have a complete example to copy-paste-compile and reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your MWE works as expected. Try to manually erase all files generated at LaTeXing of your example. This should help. This error is usually caused by editor, when it hangs on some open pdf file, so it is not really related to (La)TeX.

from your fragments of code I put together the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
    \usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 9.5in}]{geometry}
    \usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
%    \usepackage{multirow}
%    \usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}

    \begin{document}
\[
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13}\\
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\
a_{31} & a_{23} & a_{33}
\end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{c}
u_{t}^{\tau} \\
u_{t}^{g} \\
u_{t}^{y}
\end{array}\right)
=
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
b_{11} & b_{12} & b_{13}\\
b_{21} & b_{22} & b_{23}\\
b_{31} & b_{23} & b_{33}
\end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{c}
e_{t}^{\tau} \\
e_{t}^{g} \\
e_{t}^{y}
\end{array}\right)
\]
% example of use `pmatrix`
\[
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13}\\
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\
a_{31} & a_{23} & a_{33}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
u_{t}^{\tau} \\
u_{t}^{g} \\
u_{t}^{y}
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
b_{11} & b_{12} & b_{13}\\
b_{21} & b_{22} & b_{23}\\
b_{31} & b_{23} & b_{33}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
e_{t}^{\tau} \\
e_{t}^{g} \\
e_{t}^{y}
\end{pmatrix}
\]
    \end{document}
```

where I added the example of use `pmatrx` for writing of matrices. Commented packages in preamble doesn't influence on working of above code. I skip to explicit load `amsmath˙ since it is automatically loaded by`mathtools`. Obtained resulta you can see below.
[image]

Comment: Perhaps using the `pmatrix` environment would lead to a simpler code…

Comment: @Bernard, this was my idea to show another possibilities.

Comment: Great minds think alike ;o)

Comment: @Zarko thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately did not work. but Is really this matrix that seems to create the problem since as I said once I delete it the file compiles perfectly. Do you want me to show my fool code ?